# \quote{} in IEEETrans misaligns following text

Tags: quoting, ieeetran

I'm writing my LaTeX document using the [IEEE LaTeX template](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html).

I sometimes use the `\quote{some text here}` command to block quote a single paragraph. It tabs the text one to the right.

Unfortunately this causes the text below it to also be tabbed one to the right.

**How do I stop text below `\quote{}` from being misaligned?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command `\quote` doesn't officially exist: it's there only because the `quote` environment uses it internally:

```
Some text to have something to say and to start quoting
a very famous sentence
\begin{quote}
Don't use footnotes in your books, Don.
\end{quote}
which is a very good recommendation.
```

Comment: Ugh, I'm using footnotes in my book... is this bad?

Comment: @jhabbott Would you make Jill unhappy? `;-)`